# How to Save the GET Request Response Body to SQL DB in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to store the response body of the GET request to SQL DB in spring boot. Is there any way to achieve this task?

sample GET Response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "dateTime": "2020-12-02 00:00:00",
        "msisdn": 771234,
        "chargedAmount": 250.0,

    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "dateTime": "2020-12-31 23:59:58",
        "msisdn": 771234568,
        "chargedAmount": 1000.0,
    }
]
```

Comment: one of the approaches- Convert the response JSON to string and store it into varchar field of SQL table.

Answer (score 1):

you have to apply one filter in spring boot and store the request and response after successfully completing the request.
I archive the same to cache the request and response

```
@Component
public class HttpTraceFilterRepositoryManager extends OncePerRequestFilter{
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
          
            ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(
                    response);
            ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(
                    request);
            try {
                filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, wrappedResponse);
                updateBody(wrappedRequest, wrappedResponse);
            } finally {
                wrappedResponse.copyBodyToResponse();
            }
        }
        public void updateBody(ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest,
                               ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappedResponse) {
            StringBuilder requestBody = getRequestBody(wrappedRequest);
            // save in db request
            StringBuilder responseBody = getResponseBody(wrappedResponse);
            // save in db response
        }
        protected StringBuilder getResponseBody(
                ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappedResponse) {
            try {
                if (wrappedResponse.getContentSize() <= 0) {
                    return null;
                }
                byte[] srcBytes = wrappedResponse.getContentAsByteArray();
                Charset charset = Charset.forName( wrappedResponse.getCharacterEncoding());
                CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
                ByteBuffer srcBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(srcBytes);
                CharBuffer resBuffer = decoder.decode(srcBuffer);
                return new StringBuilder(resBuffer);
            } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
                logger.error(
                        "Could not read cached response body: " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
        protected StringBuilder getResponseBody(
                ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappedResponse) {
            try {
                if (wrappedResponse.getContentSize() <= 0) {
                    return null;
                }
                byte[] srcBytes = wrappedResponse.getContentAsByteArray();
                Charset charset = Charset.forName( wrappedResponse.getCharacterEncoding());
                CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
                ByteBuffer srcBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(srcBytes);
                CharBuffer resBuffer = decoder.decode(srcBuffer);
                return new StringBuilder(resBuffer);
            } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
                logger.error(
                        "Could not read cached response body: " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```